# Contentstore has more files than referenced in alf_content_url

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-content-repository

I face a weird problem, for an unknown reason, I have more files in my *contentstore* directory than the number of lines in the Alfresco table *alf_content_url*.

I've been using the simple following Unix command:

```
find contentstore -name "*.bin" | wc
```

And for the database

```
SELECT count(*) FROM alf_content_url;
```

Of course, I also dealt with the orphans so the problem is not there.

Is there a reason why files would remain in *contentstore* directory when not referenced any more in the database ?

I'm using Alfresco Community version 7.3.1 as docker containers.

Thx

Comment: I think this difference is because Contentstore contains previews and thumbnail of documents. Run your Alfresco without errors?

Comment: Where would be the previews and thumbnails referenced ?
About running without errors, that's the big question. From time to time, the transform core container throw an exception on transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 reasons for these orphaned files:

- you did a db restore to a previous point in time but kept the contentstore
- the orphanCleanup job encountered an error while removing the file

The default behaviour of the orphanCleanup job is to ignore any error:

```
# The action to take when a store or stores fails to delete orphaned content
#    IGNORE: Just log a warning.  The binary remains and the record is expunged
#    KEEP_URL: Log a warning and create a URL entry with orphan time 0.  It won't be processed or removed.
system.content.deletionFailureAction=IGNORE
```

Comment: Definitely the second case :) I'm pretty sure, there was a problem with trash can or related stuff but didn't read the comment on the deletionFailureAction config. I see a lot of reason this could have fail. Thx